# Выполнять код при покидании страницы

Tags: javascript, html, браузер, вкладки

Как реализовать выполнение скрипта, если пользователь уходит со вкладки где мой сайт(определенная страница, только на ней такое будет)? Чтобы если бы он переключился на другую или вообще закрыл/свернул окно, то код выполнялся. Если же он на нужной странице, то нет

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 1):

Есть событие [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) на закрытие окна.

Можно вешаться на события `window.blur/window.focus` чтобы детектить покидание вкладки-самый кроссбраузерный известный мне способ.
Есть [visibility api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) и [событие `visibilityChange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange) на смену вкладок. Вроде бы поддержка достаточно хорошая.

А теперь плохая новость для Вас (и хорошая для ваших пользователей): это не работает.
Ну то есть где-то работает. Везде и стабильно - нет. В мобильных браузерах наверняка будут проблемы например. Где-то может работать, но отключено на уровне настроек пользователя (я думаю в ряде популярных сборок именно так).

И самое главное, нельзя в обработчике `onbeforeunload` показывать модальные окна. Потому что когда это можно было делать, спамеры и всякие гениальные маркетологи не давали уходить с их сайта. 
На `visibilitychange` почему-то пока можно, по крайней мере в хроме. Но я бы на это не полагался.

То есть по-хорошему ответ на этот вопрос "Так делать не надо. Попробуйте решить проблему другим путем."